# How to access app package contents folder in cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have tried this code but it works for the download folder (example path: `/Users/%@/Downloads/`) not for the application folder. So I want to access  `Application/iTunes/contents/`, but I was unable to access this path.

My code:

```
- (IBAction)showTrashPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSString *trashPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Users/%@/Applications/",NSUserName()];
    ////NSLog(@"%@",trashPath);

    //[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] selectFile:trashPath inFileViewerRootedAtPath:@"Finder"];

    [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace]openFile:trashPath withApplication:@"Finder"];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually `iTunes.app` resides in folder `Applications` of the local domain rather than the user domain.

Therefore you can specify the path as literal string

```
NSString *iTunesContentsPath = @"/Applications/iTunes.app/Contents";
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openFile:iTunesContentsPath withApplication:@"Finder"];
```

But it's more reliable to ask `NSWorkspace` for the path

```
NSWorkspace *sharedWorkspace = [NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace];
NSString *iTunesPath = [sharedWorkspace fullPathForApplication:@"iTunes"];
[sharedWorkspace openFile:[iTunesPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Contents"] withApplication:@"Finder"];
```